# How to delete content in a specific page range under certain heading level/style?

Tags: vba, ms-word

Suppose I have three levels/styles of headings in a document,

[image]

I would like to know how to delete all the normal text under each instance of the third heading level/style `Heading 3` within a specific page range while keeping all the headings as they are.

Furthermore, I need to do the same to delete each table found for the same conditions after making sure the table has 11 rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
Sub DelHd3Content()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim RngFnd As Range, Rng As Range, t As Long, i As Long
Const StrHd1 As String = "General Electrical Engineering"
Const StrHd2 As String = "Systems and Artificial Intelligence"
With ActiveDocument.Range
  With .Find
    .ClearFormatting
    .Replacement.ClearFormatting
    .Replacement.Text = ""
    .Style = wdStyleHeading3
    .Forward = True
    .Wrap = wdFindStop
    .Format = True
    .Text = StrHd1
    .Execute
    If .Found = True Then
      Set RngFnd = .Parent.Paragraphs(1).Range
    Else
      MsgBox "First heading not found!", vbCritical: Exit Sub
    End If
    .Parent.Collapse wdCollapseEnd
    .Text = StrHd2
    .Execute
    If .Found = True Then
      Set Rng = .Parent.Paragraphs(1).Range
    Else
      MsgBox "Last heading not found!", vbCritical: Exit Sub
    End If
  End With
  RngFnd.End = Rng.Start
End With
With RngFnd.Duplicate
  With .Find
    .ClearFormatting
    .Replacement.ClearFormatting
    .Text = ""
    .Replacement.Text = ""
    .Style = wdStyleHeading3
    .Forward = True
    .Wrap = wdFindStop
    .Format = True
  End With
  Do While .Find.Execute
    If .InRange(RngFnd) = False Then Exit Do
    Set Rng = .Paragraphs(1).Range.GoTo(What:=wdGoToBookmark, Name:="\HeadingLevel")
    With Rng
      .Start = .Paragraphs(1).Range.End
      .Text = vbNullString: i = i + 1
      For t = .Tables.Count To 1 Step -1
        With .Tables(t)
          If .Rows.Count = 11 Then .Delete: i = i + 1
        End With
      Next
    End With
    .Collapse wdCollapseEnd
  Loop
End With
Set Rng = Nothing: Set RngFnd = Nothing
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
MsgBox i & " ranges updated.", vbOKOnly
End Sub
```

If the content under your 'Systems and Artificial Intelligence' heading is also meant to be processed, change:

```
  RngFnd.End = Rng.Start
```

to:

```
  RngFnd.End = Rng.End
```

Comment: Your code is very beautiful and took me time to partially understand every line. However, I still don't understand: **(1)** when does this line `If .InRange(RngFnd) = False Then Exit Do` get triggered if both `RngFnd` and `RngFnd.Duplicate` are identical to each other? **(2)** What is the purpose of `.Collapse wdCollapseEnd` at the end of the while loop if `RngFnd.Duplicate` is just a read-only object whose properties can't be changed? **(3)** Where can I read more about this technique `.Text = vbNullString: i = i + 1`? Thanks again for your time and informative answers.

Comment: RngFnd and RngFnd.Duplicate are identical ranges when the Find/Replace begins, but Find moves the current range to the found range. Working with a duplicate results in the new range relates to that instead of to RngFnd itself, allowing the code to check whether the found range is within RngFnd. Using .Collapse wdCollapseEnd ensures the code doesn't simply process the same range over and over. I used .Text = vbNullString instead of .Delete as the latter sometimes leaves behind a space, for example. The i = i + 1 code just updates a counter.

Answer (score 1):

For example:

```
Sub DelHd3Content()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim RngFnd As Range, Rng As Range, t As Long
With ActiveDocument
  Set RngFnd = .Range.GoTo(What:=wdGoToPage, Name:=10)
  Set Rng = .Range.GoTo(What:=wdGoToPage, Name:=20)
  RngFnd.End = Rng.End
End With
With RngFnd.Duplicate
  With .Find
    .ClearFormatting
    .Replacement.ClearFormatting
    .Text = ""
    .Replacement.Text = ""
    .Style = wdStyleHeading3
    .Forward = True
    .Wrap = wdFindStop
    .Format = True
  End With
  Do While .Find.Execute
    If .InRange(RngFnd) = False Then Exit Sub
    Set Rng = .Paragraphs(1).Range.GoTo(What:=wdGoToBookmark, Name:="\HeadingLevel")
    With Rng
      .Start = .Paragraphs(1).Range.End
      '.Text = vbNullString
      For t = .Tables.Count To 1 Step -1
        With .Tables(t)
          If .Rows.Count = 11 Then .Delete
        End With
      Next
    End With
    .Collapse wdCollapseEnd
  Loop
End With
Set Rng = Nothing
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

As coded, the macro deletes the tables on pages 10 through 20. To delete everything on those pages, uncomment '.Text = vbNullString' and (optionally) delete/comment-out the 'For t = .Tables.Count To 1 Step -1 ... Next' loop. You could leave that loop in, it would be redundant.

Comment: Many thanks for your time and effort. May I know how to specify the range of pages where the body of this heading is deleted to avoid deleting everything everywhere? For example, limit the search process between the **actual** (counted) page number `10` and `20`.

Comment: I've updated the code to process only pages 10 through 20. However, as Word uses the active printer driver to optimize the page layout, document pagination can vary depending on what printer driver is in use - even on the same system. Quite obviously, pagination is also liable to change every time you run the macro. Hence, you'd be better advised to limit the actions to a bookmarked range or between two designated headings. Given the fragility of bookmarks, the latter is preferable. Do you have such Heading3 headings you can specify? If so, specify them in your original post.

Comment: I am away from my PC at the moment, but I need to greatly appreciate your willing to help me with every question I ask, which helped me a lot in my real work. For your question, my real document has multiple instances of Heading 3 style with titles in the form of "E8.1 <first heading title>", "E8.2 <second heading title>", ...etc. Also, other sets exist such as "E7.1 <first heading title>", "E7.2 <second heading title>", ...etc.

Comment: I haven't tested, but I think _If .InRange(RngFnd) = False Then Exit Sub_ will never be executed since the Find method is applied to RngFnd.

Comment: Which is precisely why it does work. I've made a minor code revision. What are the actual titles that limit the range to process?

Comment: I have a lot of `Heading 3` titles to list them here but you can take, for example, `E4.1 General Electrical Engineering`, `E4.2 Electrical Power Systems`, `E4.3 Electronics`, `E4.4 Communication Engineering`, `E4.5 Computer Hardware`, `E4.6 Software Engineering`, `E4.7 Computer Networks`, `E4.8 Systems and Artificial Intelligence`

Comment: As I said, only the first and last is needed, viz. «you'd be better advised to limit the actions to a bookmarked range or between two designated headings. Given the fragility of bookmarks, the latter is preferable» and «What are the actual titles that limit the range to process». So, are 'General Electrical Engineering' and 'Systems and Artificial Intelligence' the first and last headings, respectively?

Comment: I am sorry I didn't totally get what you meant before. Yes, you are right, `General Electrical Engineering` and `Systems and Artificial Intelligence` are the boundaries.